# How to trigger alarm after seven days in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm trying to trigger an alarm after seven days when the user launches the app. I have tried to set the alarm to trigger in following way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MuteBroadcastReciever.class);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 747, i, 0);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7), pi);
```

But still it triggers before 7 days.

Comment: Please show exactly the code you're using.

Comment: I have edited my question @Doug Stevenson

Comment: Can you be more precise than "before 7 days"?

Comment: It triggers after a day

Answer (score 0):

From Android's [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) page:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Are you using `AlarmManager.setExact(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)` to make sure it is exact?

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.  If you are still seeking information from the OP (as your question-in-your-answer implies), then you have not yet identified the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code it may be helpful for you

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,7);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MuteBroadcastReciever.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I believe this repeats the alarm everyday. I don't intend to repeat the alarm. Just to shoot it after 7 days of the first install.

Comment: Ok...then you have require to cancel after complet your logic in reciver recive method